# Php $_SESSION value lost on iphone

Tags: php, iphone, session, cookies

As you can see here [here](http://www.gonzalohll.com/pedidos.php) my site uses sessions to send some data from pedidos.php to procesa_pedido.php.

While this works on PC, it just won't work on my iPhone.

After some research, I've found that this might have something to do with enabling cookies. I want to avoid the user from having to "accept using cookies" (not user friendly).

Any help is much appreciated. Here's the code that works on PC and not on iPhone:

First php

```
session_start();

$apunte=$row['apunte'];
$_SESSION['apunte']=$apunte;
```

Second php

```
session_start();
$apunte=$_SESSION['apunte'];
echo $apunte; echo '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, based on your description, it does sound like the issue is related to cookies. Needless to say, there's no way to have cookie-based sessions without cookies. If this is a common issue for your users, there are alternatives to cookie-based sessions. You can try passing the session ID in the URL as a GET parameter. See this php.ini setting for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies

Note that there are security issues to using this alternative approach. For example, if I log into a site and my session ID is stored in the URL, then I copy/paste that URL to my friend on Facebook, my friend will be logged in as me when they click the link (assuming the session hasn't expired yet). This is probably why the PHP manual recommends cookie-based sessions for maximum security. See: http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php

Comment: Thanks Ian. Although I was not using sessions to log to my site but just to send some parameters, your answer made me decide to use the aweful "hidden input in a GET form" method and just stop worring about cookies and such.

Comment: Great, glad that helped. And you're 100% correct: if you're only using the session to pass along non-sensitive data (e.g. some harmless user settings), and you're not using it for something like an authentication system, that eliminates most of the security risks associated with that approach.